# Echo text to a file in golang

Tags: go

Is it possible to do something in Golang similar to the below in bash

```
GrafanaProvData()
{
cat > /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml << EOF
apiVersion: 1

deleteDatasources:
  - name: Clickhouse
    orgId: 1

datasources:


  - name: Clickhouse
    type: vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource
    access: proxy
    url: http://localhost:8123
    basicAuth: 1
    basicAuthUser: default
    basicAuthPassword: $password
    isDefault: false
    defaultDatabase:


EOF
}
```

i have tried command.exec but its not exactly what is needed

Comment: Is the question essentially how to [write text to a file](https://gobyexample.com/writing-files)?

Comment: Yes and no, so yes to write to a file and no because i want to Create like templates as a function, the way bash does it

Answer (score 3):

What happens in this shell script is the usage of the so-called ["here document"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) which is piped by the shell to the [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) of the command `cat` whose standard output is directed to a file, which — due to the redirection set up using `>` — will be either created or truncated.

As commented by some folks, in Go, that would mostly amount to writing a [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) to a text file.

But note that there is a twist: when here-documents are processed by the shell it performs various expansions — including variable expansion — in the document's text before actually using it — unless special action is taken to prevent that.
So, in your example, the contents of the variable "password" would be substituted in place of `$password`.

With this in mind, what you'd do is something like

```golang
const tmpl = `apiVersion: 1

deleteDatasources:
  - name: Clickhouse
    orgId: 1

datasources:


  - name: Clickhouse
    type: vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource
    access: proxy
    url: http://localhost:8123
    basicAuth: 1
    basicAuthUser: default
    basicAuthPassword: %s
    isDefault: false
    defaultDatabase:
`

fd, err := os.OpenFile("/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml",
os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC, 0666)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
defer fd.Close()

_, err := fmt.Fprintf(tmpl, password)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

---

While we are at it, consider two more things:

- If/when the template becomes more complicated, it would become progressively harder to use the functions of the `fmt.*f` family to cut the task; you then might want to look at the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) standard package.
- If/when you would need even more advanced processing of your YAML templates, it might be more convenient to stop being format-agnostic and use any YAML-handling package for Go — such as the venerable [`gopkg.in/yaml.v3`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3) to first fill a variable of some custom compound type and then marshal it as a YAML-formatted document.
  This might help prevent a certain class of weird erorrs (consider: what happens if your password contains letters which will be interpreted by a YAML parser as a proper YAML *syntax?* A "real" YAML marshaler would escape anything which would be improperly interpreted — while any "templating" approach would not.)

---

One more hint: when the file to be written is big (like, over 10k), it might be worthwhile to stick a `bufio.Writer` between the `fmt.Fprint*` functions and the opened file—to optimize filesystem access.

Comment: that is exactly what i need!! thank you

Comment: @MikeyR, expanded on other ways to approach the problem.

Comment: you have helped a lot thanks!!